# What is the word to express 'remove the need for'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, synonyms

> Creating a spare disk will **remove the need for** more disk space.

What is the replacement for 'remove the need for'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a spare disk will **allow/create/permit/give** more disk space.

Answer (score 1):

*Obviate* is close but it only captures “remove”.

verb
verb: obviate; 3rd person present: obviates; past tense: obviated; past participle: obviated; gerund or present participle: obviating

remove (a need or difficulty).
"the Venetian blinds obviated the need for curtains"

Comment: So I am looking for a single word to replace the following `obviated the need for`, `remove the need for`....

Comment: @variable I don't think there's a single word, but if you just say "obviate more disk space" it will be understood.